# How to add spaces in the JavaScript import in Clang-Format

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, clang-format

Here is the code snippet in my TypeScript/JavaScript file:

```js
import { Component,    OnInit } from    '@angular/core';
```

The **Clang-Format** will format my code into this:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
```

But I'd like to use **Clang-Format** format my code into this.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

I want to add one space between `{` and `Component` and add one space between `OnInit` and `}`, but I couldn't find any [Clang-Format Style Options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) to set that.  Is there anyway to configure this?

Comment: did you ever find an answer/workaround for this? I'm trying to figure this out as well

Comment: @MattewWhitt I use [Prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) now.  It's awesome and can fully replace the **Clang-Format**!